# Tracking all network interactions for a java application

Tags: networking, java, tracking

There's a helper client for this game I'm playing, however, it's closed source and I know nothing about what goes on with it. I want to make sure it's not sending out any sensitive information such as username/password, is there any way for me to monitor all outgoing requests the java app is sending?

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, but if it's malware and they're smart the packets will probably be encrypted.

ED: Wireshark actually will not work because it does not map port to PID (even though it could). What you really want to use is [Microsoft's tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) which will let you filter by process. Note that with a Java application the executable / PID will likely be java.exe, javaw.exe, etc rather than having a bespoke name.

Comment: this is a potencial answer, but still being jus t a comment, improve it.

Comment: Done deal, and wouldn't have actually worked.